# GIT and VMWare/Volumes

Tags: git, vmware, clone, commit, push

I have MacBook and Ubuntu Server on it as part of VMWare fusion virtual machine. When I use GIT on my local disk (Mac) everything is working perfectly but when I try to use git on volumes I have problems.

For example /Volumes/vm1/webfolder is my local .git repository. If I create clone like

```
git@myserver:byrepo.git
```

then I check for changes like

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

all files differs and need update. What is the problem? For info... the same effect I get using shared VMWare folders on Windows. Is there permission problem or user owner problem?

Fix for it?
Thx!

Comment: Please go back to some of your older questions (there are links on your account page) and accept answers - people deserve credit for the help they've given.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit of trouble telling exactly what your problem is, but if you're saying that `git-pull` refuses to act, stating that everything has been modified, it is quite possible you their permissions have changed. Check the output of `git diff` to confirm this, and if it's the case and it's safe to ignore permission changes, try setting core.filemode to false:

```
git config core.filemode false
```